# ion-item bug when display result in class

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I place the result inside the ion-item class it breaks the code, if i delete the `{{i.categoria}}` he works, but i need get the result inside the class.

Look my code

```
<ion-list class="list-praia">
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of array" class="categoria-item all {{i.categoria}}">
    ..
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: can you give some explanation about your `class = "categoria-item all {{i.cateforia}}"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ionic but I'd suggest you use `ngClass` instead of string interpolation in the `class` attribute

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of array" 
    class="categoria-item all"
    [ngClass]="i.categoria">
```